# Undefined Reference / Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c, winsock, undefined-reference, unresolved-external

I'm trying to use WinSock.h header file, but I get either one of the errors below:
in VS2010 (C++):

```
Unresolved External Symbol to [the function included in winsock.g, e.g socket()]
```

in gcc command line (C):

```
Undefined Reference to [the function included in winsock.g, e.g socket()]
```

code is simple: Just including the Winsock.h header file and then

```
SOCKET s =  socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

I get an error on `socket()` & `closesocket()` functions...!
I searched in Stackoverflow and found several topics over this, but they all suggested a change in the header file. I can't change WinSock.h here, so I need a solution in the actual code that uses the header file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need `ws2_32.lib`.

Go to Project->Properties->Linker->Additional dependencies and add `ws2_32.lib`.

EDIT:

That should be Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but i can't find additional dependencies. I have General, Input, Manifest File, Debugging, System, Optimization, Embedded DLL, Advanced, Command Line.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I found a boolean property called Link Library Dependencies, in General Tab, which is set to "Yes".

Comment: The "Additional Dependencies" entry is in Input; corrected above.

Comment: For Future Viewers: Another solution is adding #pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lin") or #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") before including the winsock2.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

Those are linker errors, not compiler errors.  You need to link the WinSock library.  For gcc,  that means adding the library to your link command line:

```
gcc -Lpath/to/winsock/library -o myApplication myObject.o wsock32.lib
```

I don't know anything about Visual Studio, I'm afraid, but [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help.

Comment: I'm assuming this is gcc [App_To_Be_Compiled] -L [Path to the winsock library] -o [output_exe]

Comment: Which means that I have to link the library everytime I compile it, or is there another way to link it permanently?

Comment: Hi. did this and still the same error:                              gcc C:\Socket.c -L C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll -o C:\out.exe